# Elementary OS on new machine (Lenovo Thinkpad L490) has hiccups and internet issues

Tags: linux, wifi, elementary-os, freeze, thinkpad

**EDIT**: It seems like these problems mostly happen when I try to download something, anything, and the effect is most pronounced with large files. Sometimes this is followed by multiple prolonged and excruciating freezes of the system. I am extremely annoyed, can someone please help me to fix this?

I am not very knowledgable about the intricacies of Linux, but I have used elementary OS on my old laptop (Thinkpad T420) without any major issues. Now I have gotten a new one, and it has some problems that I didn't experience before:
- It has relatively frequent freezes during normal usage (i.e. surfing or text editor), even though memory and CPU don't seem to be anywhere near the limit.
- The internet connection breaks off frequenty, even though it is fine on my other machine. The wifi driver seems to be installed though.

I know that this is a rather broad question, but I don't really know where to start. Might this even be a BIOS issue?

EDIT:
`cat /proc/release` yields "No such file or directory".
`cat /etc/os-release` yields

```
NAME="elementary OS"
VERSION="5.1.3 Hera"
ID=elementary
ID_LIKE=ubuntu
PRETTY_NAME="elementary OS 5.1.3 Hera"
LOGO=distributor-logo
VERSION_ID="5.1.3"
HOME_URL="https://elementary.io/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://elementary.io/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://github.com/elementary/os/issues/new"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://elementary.io/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=hera
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

and `cat /proc/version` yields

```
Linux version 5.3.0-46-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-013) (gcc version 
7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)) #38~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 31 
04:17:56 UTC 2020
```

EDIT: I just had one of the wifi-problems again. Had connection to the router, but no internet (while I did have internet on another device). After a while I turned the wifi off and on again, and shortly after, it resumed working. Here is the output of `tail /var/log/syslog`:

```
Apr 28 20:30:01 ge0rg-ThinkPad-L490 colord[844]: failed to get session 
[pid 816]: No data available
Apr 28 20:30:01 ge0rg-ThinkPad-L490 acvpnagent[823]: Function: 
logProbeFailure File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 1524 
The HTTP probe to 128.139.30.66 resulted in a redirect.
Apr 28 20:30:01 ge0rg-ThinkPad-L490 acvpnagent[823]: Function: 
analyzeHttpResponse File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 
1840 SG (128.139.30.66) contacted
Apr 28 20:30:01 ge0rg-ThinkPad-L490 acvpnagent[823]: Current network 
state: Secure Gateway accessible
Apr 28 20:30:03 ge0rg-ThinkPad-L490 nm-dispatcher: req:6 
'connectivity-change': new request (2 scripts)
Apr 28 20:30:03 ge0rg-ThinkPad-L490 nm-dispatcher: req:6 
'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
Apr 28 20:30:05 ge0rg-ThinkPad-L490 systemd-resolved[696]: Using 
degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 192.168.0.1.
Apr 28 20:30:10 ge0rg-ThinkPad-L490 plank.desktop[1559]: 
[1722:1740:0428/203010.396690:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(420)] 
Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -105
Apr 28 20:30:20 ge0rg-ThinkPad-L490 systemd-resolved[696]: Using 
degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 
2a02:8109:9c80:3ee8:10:18ff:fec6:6f0c.
Apr 28 20:30:28 ge0rg-ThinkPad-L490 systemd-resolved[696]: Using 
degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 
2a02:8109:9c80:3ee8:10:18ff:fec6:6f0c.
```

hereafter, it happened again. Both times, it happened when I tried to `git clone` something, if that is of any help. In the past, these disconnects also often happened when I tried to download some file. Here is the output after the recent wifi trouble:

```
Apr 28 20:36:04 ge0rg-ThinkPad-L490 acvpnagent[823]: Function: 
logProbeFailure File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 1524 
The HTTP probe to 128.139.30.66 resulted in a redirect.
Apr 28 20:36:04 ge0rg-ThinkPad-L490 acvpnagent[823]: Function: 
analyzeHttpResponse File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 
1840 SG (128.139.30.66) contacted
Apr 28 20:36:04 ge0rg-ThinkPad-L490 acvpnagent[823]: Current network 
state: Secure Gateway accessible
Apr 28 20:36:06 ge0rg-ThinkPad-L490 systemd-resolved[696]: Using 
degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 
2a02:8109:9c80:3ee8:10:18ff:fec6:6f0c.
Apr 28 20:36:07 ge0rg-ThinkPad-L490 NetworkManager[750]: <info>  
[1588098967.5734] manager: NetworkManager state is now 
CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Apr 28 20:36:07 ge0rg-ThinkPad-L490 nm-dispatcher: req:6 
'connectivity-change': new request (2 scripts)
Apr 28 20:36:07 ge0rg-ThinkPad-L490 nm-dispatcher: req:6 
'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
Apr 28 20:36:07 ge0rg-ThinkPad-L490 nm-applet[1612]: 
gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Apr 28 20:36:07 ge0rg-ThinkPad-L490 nm-applet[1612]: 
gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Apr 28 20:36:07 ge0rg-ThinkPad-L490 nm-applet[1612]: Can't set a 
parent on widget which has a parent
```

EDIT: Here is the most recent log. Again, during `git clone`, which seems to happen rather consistently. As opposed to the other two, I ran the command before reconnecting (I don't know whether that's relevant):

```
Apr 28 20:40:55 ge0rg-ThinkPad-L490 kernel: [ 5076.816348] iwlwifi 

0000:05:00.0: 0x0000485B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
Apr 28 20:40:55 ge0rg-ThinkPad-L490 kernel: [ 5076.816452] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: 0x0BADCAFE | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
Apr 28 20:40:55 ge0rg-ThinkPad-L490 kernel: [ 5076.816504] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Collecting data: trigger 2 fired.
Apr 28 20:40:55 ge0rg-ThinkPad-L490 kernel: [ 5076.816513] ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
Apr 28 20:40:55 ge0rg-ThinkPad-L490 systemd-resolved[696]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 192.168.0.1.
Apr 28 20:40:56 ge0rg-ThinkPad-L490 kernel: [ 5077.612625] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
Apr 28 20:40:56 ge0rg-ThinkPad-L490 kernel: [ 5077.728736] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
Apr 28 20:40:56 ge0rg-ThinkPad-L490 kernel: [ 5077.805262] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
Apr 28 20:40:56 ge0rg-ThinkPad-L490 wpa_supplicant[754]: wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-48 noise=9999 txrate=144400
Apr 28 20:41:04 ge0rg-ThinkPad-L490 io.elementary.t[7031]: gtk_box_gadget_distribute: assertion 'size >= 0' failed in GtkNotebook
```

Comment: also, next time your system freezes, try to run `tail /var/log/syslog` afterward

Comment: @rubaiat: `/proc/release`, what is that? Did you mean `/proc/version`?

Comment: run `cat /proc/version` and `cat /etc/os-release` and share us the info. thanks, @Arkadiusz Drabczyk

Comment: @rubaiat: did that, see edit. When the next freeze happens, I'll make sure to run the other command.

Comment: I've seen people using kernel version `5.3.0-` or more facing similar situations. How about downgrading to a more stable kernel?

Comment: Can you point me to a tutorial on how to do that wothout braking my system? Also, what Kernel version would you suggest?

Comment: I hope the situation is clearer now that I added the output of the last command.